# How to do Schematron validation over different xml files attributes

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-validation, schematron

I have one source1.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<list>
  <author id="a1">Alice</author>
  <author id="p1">Paul</author>
  <author id="p2">Peter</author>
</list>
```

another source2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<list>
  <author id="1"/>
  <author id="a2"/>
  <author id="p1"/>
</list>
```

I need to validate "id" attribute of the two xml files are having same values or not.
I can do it using the schematron as shown in this link ( http://zvon.org/xxl/SchematronTutorial/Examples/Example17/example.html)

So I have created on xsd file (source2.xsd) where my schematron is included as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="list">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="author">

          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <sch:pattern name ="Compare AdaptiveDisplayDevice Id with DisplayDevice Id" xmlns:sch="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron">

                <rule context="author">
                  <report test="document('source1.xml')//author[@id=current()/@id]">
                    Atrribute
                    <name path="document('source1.xml')//author[@id=current()/@id]"/> is forbidden in element
                    <name/>
                  </report>
                </rule>

              </sch:pattern>
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>

          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

My C# code to validation is as shown below

```
using System.Text;
using NMatrix.Schematron;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {

                /* setup schematron validation */
                Validator validator = new Validator();
                validator.AddSchema(@"D:\POC\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\source2.xsd");

                /* run both validators at once */
                validator.Validate(new XmlTextReader(@"D:\POC\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\source2.xml"));

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

        }
    } 
}
```

If we observe two xml files , then while validation using schematron it should give me error at first two id values. However I am not getting any error ..
Can anyone help me here ....

Comment: So your problem appears to be:  how do I make the C# schema validator enforce Schematron rules embedded in an XSD schema document?  Have you checked that the C# XSD validator supports embedded Schematron rules?

Comment: Yes, c# validator support embedded schematron, I tried it n its working fine for the same file...

Comment: It is jst not giving me any error for different file attributes validation,  as shown in above example. If I do any validation over attributes of same file then it shows me error...  I m nt sure anything wrong wit my xpath mentioned for different files attributes..